# How to make search functionality in android?

Tags: android, full-text-search

Hello i am making an small application in which i want search functionality i had done surfing on Internet but i didn't get anything useful.
could you give any tutorial or anything so that i can made search functionality in my application.

Comment: i have few images i want to search that images with search functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a very close look to the [Search section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html) on Android developper website.

Basically you need to create a Searchable activity in your application by declaring it in the manifest :

```
<activity android:name="SearchActivity" android:excludeFromRecents="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

This activity will handle any search request made when the user uses his phone's search button. The search query (what the user typed in the text field) will appear in the intent calling your search activity. You can use it like this in your activity onResume() method :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH)) {
    String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
    // do something with the query... 
}
```

Comment: How can i show the search box

Comment: You can call the Activity.startSearch(...) method, which is called by the default Activity.onSearchRequested() method. You can override onSearcRequested to create your own UI, but then you need to send your own intent.

Comment: @Amandeep singh: Follow the link provided in the first line of the answer, there are code samples and everything that you need.